# Why are those inequalities always true?

Tags: inequality, summation

Here are two inequalities that i don't know how to explain.

- $\text{For }n\in\mathbb N^* \text{ and } (a_1,...,a_n)\in(\mathbb R^{+})^n\text{ , }
  \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2a_k}\le\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt{\sum_{s=k}^{n}a_s}$
- $\text{For }n\in\mathbb N^* \text{ , } (a_1,...,a_n)\in\mathbb R^n\text{ and }(b_1,...,b_n)\in\mathbb R^n\text{ such that }a_1\le...\le a_n \text{ and } b_1\le...\le b_n , \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k\right)\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}b_k\right)\le\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_kb_k\right)$

Why are those inequalities always true?

Comment: You really should ask only one question per post, unless they are _very_ closely related (such as asking about several parts of the same proof, or where the solution to one question is obviously going to be applied in the next question). That way, someone like me, who can only answer one of them, can actually address everything.

Comment: Ok sorry ! I won't do this again !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second inequality results from multiple applications of the [rearrangement inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality), which gives us
$$
a_1b_k+a_2b_{k+1}+\cdots+a_{n-k+1}b_n+a_{n-k+2}b_1+\cdots+a_nb_{k-1}\leq a_1b_1+a_2b_2+\cdots+a_nb_n
$$
for all $2\leq k\leq n$.

Answer (score 2):

For the first inequality, let

$x_k=\sqrt{\sum_{s=k}^n a_s}$, RHS becomes $\sum_{k=1}^n x_k$

It's easy to show that LHS $= \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n (2k-1)x_k^2}$

We now prove that $LHS^2 <= RHS^2$

Note that $x_1 \ge x_2 \ge \cdots \ge x_n$

$x_1^2=x_1^2$

$(2k-1)x_k^2 = (2k-1) x_k \cdot x_k \le \left(\sum_{s=1}^k x_s + \sum_{s=1}^{k-1} x_s \right) x_k = \left( \sum_{s=1}^k x_s \right)^2 - \left( \sum_{s=1}^{k-1} x_s \right)^2, \forall k\ge 2$

Therefore $LHS^2 \le x_1^2 + \sum_{k=2}^n \left( \left( \sum_{s=1}^k x_s \right)^2 - \left( \sum_{s=1}^{k-1} x_s \right)^2 \right) =\left(\sum_{s=1}^n x_s \right)^2 = RHS^2$. Q.E.D.

Comment: I have one question. Why is $(2k-1) x_k \cdot x_k \le \left(\sum_{s=1}^k x_s + \sum_{s=1}^{k-1} x_s \right) x_k$ ?

Comment: Ok i understand !